# Site is broken after transferring to adminer

Tags: migration

I have a very serious problem.. I have this dev site done using PhpMyAdmin http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/clickzac/ and my client wants me to transfer the site. But their server don't have PhpMyAdmin and had to use Adminer, after transferring the database the website becomes like this http://kjrias.com I really don't know what's happening.. I tried to fix it on my own but I did not even made it...

Steps for transferring the site:

1. on my server, I zipped and donwloaded the wp-content.
2. i downloaded the sql file of the database..
3. using text editor, I replaced the dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/clickzac with kjrias.com
4. On their site, I uploaded the adminer-3.3.4-en.php inside the wordress folder.
5. replaced the wp-content with my wp-content and then imported the database

Comment: is there any one who can help me? I think the problem is the theme, the theme is not working just like in the previous server. after transferring the website, the site is totally different.. please :'(

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the site? Describe your problem in a way other visitors can benefit from.

Comment: In your comment to aprea's answer you describe some important info that should be on your question. As a matter of fact, as toscho points out, for your question to be a good one, that's exactly the info that should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**
[Chrome's](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) console, or [Safari's](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox are essential tools for a developer.
Here's a snapshot that shows exactly what's going wrong with your site: you still have urls that point to the old address.
[image: error snapshot]

**Observation**
Adminer is a wonderful tool, but if your server don't have PhpMyAdmin that's really a bad sign and may lead to other issues down the road.

**Manual migration**
Don't do a normal search/replace in your database, as there are options that are serialized and simply break if the strings don't have exactly the same length.

Import the original database again (with the old address).
Upload this script ([Safe Search and Replace on Database with Serialized Data](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/searchreplacedb2.php)) side by side with your `wp-config.php`.
When you run it, go ahead with the default options. Make sure you are selecting the right tables (in case you have others living in the same DB).
Now search and replace the old with the new url (without the last forward slash).

I'm not sure if that `vslider/timthumb` address are recorded with url escaping in the database.
Probably not, but if they are, search for:
`http%3A%2F%2Fdev.freelanceu.net%2Fmjl%2Fclickzac%2F`
and replace with:
`http%3A%2F%2Fkjrias.com%2F`

These are the old and new urls with a forward slash at the end.

### [update]

Even when using BackupBuddy, I run the mentioned script, as for me BB don't work 100% when migrating.

**Important**: first run the search/replace **with** `http://` in the string, and run it a second time **without** it.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out, I am new with this problem, I already developed websites and I transferred it successfully. I did migrating just by search and replacing the URLs, i didn't know that there are still URLs that did not replaced . Thank you so much buddy, New knowledge :)

Comment: Glad to know that you figured it out, but remember it's not only that URLs don't get replaced, it's URLs that are **badly** replaced inside *serialized* arrays!

Answer (score 0):

How did you migrate the website? There's obviously quite a few broken elements. Have you tried following the steps outlined here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

You can also try using a premium plugin to migrate this site, I personally use BackupBuddy, it works very nicely, check it out here: http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Comment: I already transferred a websites and it was successful, the only difference was this website has no PHPmyAdmin, so that's why I have to use adminer.. 

I am using wordpress 3.3.1 and here are my steps of transferring the site. 

1. on my server, I zipped and donwloaded the wp-content. 

2. i downloaded the sql file of the database..

3. using text editor, I replaced the dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/clickzac with kjrias.com 
4. On their site, I uploaded the adminer-3.3.4-en.php inside the wordress folder. 

5. replaced the wp-content with my wp-content and then imported the database.. thats it. :(

Comment: Did you update the database with the new url? This from the codex: you must change "siteurl" and "home" in the database table "wp_options" (through phpMyAdmin or similar).